# Express fails to find resources in case of parameterized route. What am I missing?

Tags: node.js, express, parameters, routes

In my express app I have a separate file for middlewares. I used express.static to make the resources available to the app. Code from middlewares.js...

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static('node_modules/vue/dist'));
app.use(express.static('node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css'));
app.use(express.static('node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js'));
app.use(express.static('node_modules/multiple.js'));
app.use(express.static('node_modules/chart.js/dist'));
```

It works fine for all the routes. However, when I try to define a parameterized route, and render a template this way, it fails to load up the resources. Express fails to find CSS/JS/Image files from those statics. What am I missing here? Here is my code for the route..

```
app.get('/invoices/:id', app.authenticated, (req, res) => {
    Invoices.find({_id: req.params.id}, (err, invoice) => {
        if (err) {
            res.json({error: err});
        }
        res.render('invoicesCreate');
    });
});
```

Updated: The View file

```
{{#section 'classes'}}has-navigation page-dashboard{{/section}}
{{#section 'body-classes'}}-fluid{{/section}}
 <div class="row" id="invoicer">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
   Fill your details and get live preview in the right side
     <form class="" action="/invoices" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="">
    <div class="invoiceform-logo-container">
      <input type="file" name="profilelogo" id="fileinput" accept="image/*" v-on:change="updateImage()">
      <img v-bind:src="logo" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="invoiceform-number"></div>
    <div class="invoiceform-currency"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="">
    Your Name / Company Name
    <textarea name="company_name" rows="8" cols="40" v-model="from"></textarea>
    Client Name / Company Name
    <textarea name="client_name" rows="8" cols="40" v-model="to"></textarea>

    \{{date_title}}
    <input type="date" name="start_date" v-model="date">

    \{{due_date_title}}
    <input type="date" name="end_date" v-model="due_date" v-bind:min="date">

    \{{balance_title}} \{{balance}}
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
      <input name="end_date" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="invoiceform-itemlist" v-on:focusout="checkToRemove()">
    <div class="">
      \{{item_header}}
      \{{quantity_header}}
      \{{unit_cost_header}}
      \{{amount_header}}
    </div>
    <div class="" v-for="item in items">
      <input type="text" name="items[1][item_name]" v-model="item.head">
      <input type="number" name="items[1][item_quantity]" v-model="item.quantity" min="0" v-on:blur="updateAmount($index)">
      <input type="number" name="items[1][item_rate]" v-model="item.rate" min="0" v-on:blur="updateAmount($index)">
      <input type="number" name="items[1][item_amount]" v-model="item.amount">
    </div>
    <button type="button" name="button">Add Item</button>
  </div>

  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="">
    \{{subtotal_title}} \{{subtotal}}
    \{{tax_title}}

    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" v-model="tax">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <input type="radio" name="" aria-label="Checkbox for following text input"> %
      </span>
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <input type="radio" name="" aria-label="Checkbox for following text input"> F
      </span>
    </div>

    <div id="discount" v-if="fields.discount">
      Discount <input type="number" name="" v-model="discounts">
    </div>
    <div id="shipping" v-if="fields.shipping">
      Shipping <input type="number" name="shipping" v-model="shipping">
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" name="discount" v-model="fields.discount"> \{{discounts_title}}
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" name="shipping" v-model="fields.shipping"> \{{shipping_title}}
      </label>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="">
    Total <input type="number" name="name" v-model="total" min="0">
    \{{amount_paid_title}} <input type="number" name="total" v-model="amount_paid" min="0" v-bind:max="total">
  </div>

  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="">
    \{{notes_title}}
    <input type="text" name="name" v-model="notes">
    \{{payment_terms_title}}
    <input type="text" name="name" v-model="terms">
    <button type="submit" name="button">Save Now</button>
    <button type="button" name="button">Download PDF</button>
  </div>
</form>

     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 hidden-sm-down"></div>
   </div>
 {{#section 'script'}}
  window.invoice = {{{json defaultInvoice}}}
  console.log({{{json defaultInvoice}}})
 {{/section}}
```

Comment: does it throw any error also?

Comment: can you paste the contents of your invoicesCreate view

Comment: it is probably returning the json because the condition `if(err) res.json({error: err}); ` is satisfied.

Comment: No, it does not throw any error. However, there are other problems if I use parameterized routes. Couldn't handle the parameter as it shows not a single value but resources as an object.